# How do you move free space to front of a hard drive in use so a system can boot?

Tags: veracrypt

Sitaution:

Dual-Boot Laptop, 2 drives in it, a SSD and a HDD

Windows 10 , and 8.1(which was installed second)

My goal: To fully encrypt the 8.1 drive so Windows 10 (which I've never really connected to the internet) can't look into the drive , and telemetry can't scoop any tidbits of data. Then I can go ahead and use Windows 10 for limited reasons like VR.

When I tried: - I went to Veracrypt and selected Encrypt- and got this:

https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/technical/thread/f4f1fb60/50bd/attachment/Veracrypt_2.PNG

So I thought- all i need is to get 32 kb of free space in front. Following advice i'd seen at places on here, on Reddit, etc-

I then Made a Macrium Reflect backup of the 8.1 drive partitions, including the OS and the hidden 128 mb microsoft reserved partition in front(that you can't see using Windows' own tools, but Gparted will).

I put Gparted on a flash drive, booted from it,  moved my entire 8.1 install to the right, put some empty space in front-the machine would not boot after this. 
Hence me then panicking and trying not to have lost everything

Backups from Macrium (rescue boot cd)did NOT work in fixing this- I  chased down a installation CD of 8.1, THEN, put macrium on the new install of 8.1, tried to load image of 8.1- it  still wouldn't boot. Used Macrium's (this time via the macrium rescue cd) fix MBR option- only then did the recovered 8.1 boot.

I don't want to go through that hell again as this was a close one, but i'd like to be able to encrypt my system.

How do you properly move space, so that your system will boot? I thought it has to do with flags- but I can't seem to find solid answers on this..

Comment: Are you booting with UEFI or CSM/legacy/BIOS? Can you post a screenshot from GParted?

Answer (score 0):

Windows really doesn’t like to move, I hate to say. Certain files in windows, such as file tables, have their locations set at install, and windows won’t let you move them. You can try and use 3rd party software, but that has risks (as you found) The only surefire way to move it is to re-install 8.1, as the veracrypt message hints. During your install, manually select the location and give yourself the space you need for encryption.